# YABLS? (Yet Another Boot Loop Snafu?)

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, twrp, boot-loop, heimdall

So I have read through quite a few bootloop posts but still haven't managed to resolve my issue (am very close to trying oden 2 linux...).

**Device**: samsung galaxy tab a (sm-t350)

**what I did**: Using heimdall I sucessfully flashed twrp to my tablet. Noticed I had forgotten to dl the rom (lineage retiredtab) so booted into stock android, downloaded the rom, then booted back into twrp and flashed the [lineage retiredtab rom](https://xdaforums.com/t/unofficial-rom-beta-lineageos-18-1-go-for-galaxy-tab-a-sm-t350-dec-12-2023.4305903/), then rebooted.

**What happened:** when i rebooted I am stuck in a bootloop i guess? and no matter what I do i can't seem to do anything other than reboot and boot into "odin mode". I can't boot into recovery and I can't power down.
the many of the button combinations seems to require the device be off, but as i can't power off I can't seem to use them.

**What I can do:** I can get to the odin mode "downloading" screen - and I can flash twrp (I just can't boot into twrp) and I can reboot - which just takes me to the lineage booting animation.

Comment: One common problem is that volume buttons break and are detected as permanently pressed by the device. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for the response (I'm getting desperate here). I dont think the buttons are broken, I am able to use the down vol/home/power buttons to successfully get to the ODIN MODE/Downloading screen and then use the up volume to continue (to odin mode).

Comment: no one else? Please let me know if there is any more info that I need to add?